# Return array/object to jquery script from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello all and thanks in advance,

Short story, I am using a plugin to dynamically populate select options and am trying to do it via an ajax call but am struggling with getting the data into the select as the select gets created before the ajax can finish.

First, I have a plugin that sets up different selects. The `options` input can accept an array or object and creates the `<option>` html for the select. The createModal code is also setup to process a function supplied for the `options` input. Example below;

```
$('#modalAccounts').createModal({
    {
        component: 'select',
        options: function () {
            let dueDate = {};
                for (let i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
                    dueDate[i] = i;
                }
            return dueDate;
        }
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is provide an object to the `options` input via AJAX. I have a plugin called postFind which coordinates the ajax call. Items such as database, collection, etc. are passed to the ajax call. Functions that should be executed post the ajax call are pass through using the onSuccess option.

```
(function ($) {
    $.extend({
        postFind: function () {
            var options = $.extend(true, {
                onSuccess: function () {}
            }, arguments[0] || {});
            options.data['action'] = 'find';
            $.ajax({
                url: "../php/ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: options.data,
                statusCode: {
                    404: function () {
                        alert("Page not found");
                    }
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
                    if (obj.success) {
                        if (typeof options.onSuccess === 'function') {
                            options.onSuccess.call(this, obj);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, text, err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The plugin works fine as when I look at the output it is the data I expect. Below is an example of the initial attempt.

```
$('#modalAccounts').createModal({
    {
        component: 'select',
        options: function () {
            $.postFind({
                data: {
                    database: 'dashboard',
                    collections: {
                        accountTypes: {
                            where: {status: true}
                        }
                    }
                },
                onSuccess: function (options) {
                    let dataArray = {};
                    $.each(options, function (key, val) {
                        dataArray[val._id.$oid] = val.type;
                    });
                    return dataArray;
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

In differnt iterations of attempting things I have been able to get the data back to the options but still not as a  in the select.

After doing some poking around it looks like the createModal script in executing and creating the select before the AJAX call can return options. In looking at things it appears I need some sort of promise of sorts that returns the options but (1) I am not sure what that looks like and (2) I am not sure where the promise goes (in the plugin, in the createModal, etc.)

Any help you can provide would be great!

---

**Update**: Small mistake when posted, need to pass the results back to the original call: `options.onSuccess.call(this, obj);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe to use variables inside your success callback they have to be defined properties inside your ajax call. Then to access the properties use `this` inside the callback. Like:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "../php/ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: options.data,
            myOptions: options,
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert("Page not found");
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
                if (obj.success) {
                    if (typeof this.myOptions.onSuccess === 'function') {
                        this.myOptions.onSuccess.call(this);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, text, err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with the `options.onSuccess` call the functions, in fact the call passes the results of the ajax back to the original script. The problem I am having is the original `.createModal` function finishes before the results can be supplied.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me where the problem is without access to a functional example. I would start with a simplified version of what you want to do that demonstrates the proper functionality. My guess is the callbacks aren't setup exactly correctly; I would want to see the network call stack before making a more definitive statement. A few well-placed `console.log()` statements would probably give you a better idea of how the code is executing.

I wrote and tested the following code that removes most of the complexity from your snippets. It works by populating the select element on page load.

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select data-src='test.php' data-id='id' data-name='name'></select>
  </body>
</html>
<html>

<script>
$('select[data-src]').each(function() {
  var $select = $(this);
  $select.append('<option></option>');

  $.ajax({
    url: $select.attr('data-src'),
    data: {'v0': 'Alligator', 'v1': 'Crocodile'}
  }).then(function(options) {
    options.map(function(option) {
      var $option = $('<option>');
      $option
        .val (option[$select.attr('data-id')])
        .text(option[$select.attr('data-name')]);
      $select.append($option);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

And the PHP file:

```
<?php   
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode([
  [ 'id' => 0, 'name' => 'Test User 0' ],
  [ 'id' => 3, 'name' => $_GET['v0']   ],
  [ 'id' => 4, 'name' => $_GET['v1']   ]
]);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgah0bcv/3/) that also demonstrates the behavior.